# How to convert date format from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-6

I have some confused in here, when I was made a method to convert date format in `javascript` to `php`, my date is not right when in `javascript` `console` result is `2020/7/1` but in my `php` result is `2020-01-07` when I use `date('Y-m-d')` method. For full script I put in below for more continous understanding to my problem :

my `app.js` :

```
// get today
const today = new Date();

// get month of today
const todayInMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;

// get year of today
const todayInYear = today.getFullYear();

// count date in one month (today)
const countDayInMonth = new Date(todayInYear, todayInMonth, 0).getDate();

// get number 15 of date
let dividerOne;
countDayInMonth == '31' ? dividerOne = Math.floor(countDayInMonth / 2) : countDayInMonth == '30' ? dividerOne = countDayInMonth / 2 : countDayInMonth == '29' ? dividerOne = Math.round(countDayInMonth / 2) : dividerOne = Math.ceil(countDayInMonth / 2);

// get number 15 / 16 of date
let dividerTwo = countDayInMonth - dividerOne;

// get fist date in every month
let firstDate = new Date(todayInYear, todayInMonth - 1, 1).toLocaleDateString();

$.ajax({
    url: "myController/getMyFunction",
    method: "POST",
    data: {firstDate: firstDate},
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
})
```

my `myController.php` :

```
public function getMyFunction(Request $list) {
    $firstDate = $list->firstDate;

    //change '/' to '-' and read to YYYY-MM-DD
    $raw_firstDate = strtr($firstDate, '/', '-');
    $fix_firstDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($raw_firstDate));

    echo json_encode($fix_firstDate);
}
```

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: Seems like a local problem to me. If I use your php function and pass the string directly, everything works fine. Please echo the passed date inside the php function BEFORE you manipulate anything and see what's the output.

Comment: the result is like this `"7\/1\/2020" (m-d-Y)`

Comment: hm seems strange to me. Because if I see it correctly, the date seems to be correct and also month / date is fine.

Comment: same with me, I'm not understand about this one, cause this problem is really make me confused, oh ya can I change method to `date('Y-d-m')` for exchange date format from `javascript`? But I'm afraid it will got a problem to next step :)

Comment: Why do you want to deliver the local time to the server without information about the time zone? I think a new date (..) / 1000 timestamp is better.

Comment: cause I wanna use for some condition in my code, but thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem with another way, I'm to stuck about this problem and I change my style of code to this :

first of all I make my variable into an array, then make them `join()` with `-` connector, like this `(app.js)` :

```
// get today
const today = new Date();
// get year of today
const todayInYear = today.getFullYear();
// get month of today
let todayInMonth = '' + today.getMonth();
todayInMonth.length < 2 ? todayInMonth = '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1) : todayInMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
// count date in one month (today)
const countDayInMonth = new Date(todayInYear, todayInMonth, 0).getDate().toString();
// get number 15 of date
let dividerOne;
countDayInMonth == '31' ? dividerOne = Math.floor(countDayInMonth / 2) : countDayInMonth == '30' ? dividerOne = countDayInMonth / 2 : countDayInMonth == '29' ? dividerOne = Math.round(countDayInMonth / 2) : dividerOne = Math.ceil(countDayInMonth / 2);
// get number 15 / 16 of date
let dividerTwo = countDayInMonth - dividerOne;
// get fist date in every month
let firstDate = [todayInYear, todayInMonth, "0" + 1].join("-");
// get date range 1 - 15
let rangeOne = [todayInYear, todayInMonth, dividerOne].join("-");
// get date range 15 / 16 - end
let rangeTwo = [todayInYear, todayInMonth, dividerTwo].join("-");
// get last date in every month
let lastDate = [todayInYear, todayInMonth, countDayInMonth].join("-");
```

and for my code in `controller` I just called my data from my `js` code, like this :

```
public function getMyFunction(Request $list) {
    $firstDate = $list->firstDate;

    echo json_encode($fix_firstDate);
}
```

I wanna say thanks to everyone want to help me solve my problem, I hope my code will be easy to understand and can be useful for others, happy nice code